# Accessing Service Layer from custom Controller in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I am new to Spring and ROO and this Annotation/Aspect hell.

I have an Spring MVC Project created with Spring ROO.
I use mongo-db as my persistance layer.
I have an entity `Report` with the domain object, the service, the repository and the controller.
I added a custom controller wich workes so far.
I want to just access my stored reports with the `ReportService.findAllReports()`, but I'm not sure how to get access to this service.

Here is a link to my roo generated site http://sauberseite.cloudfoundry.com/

The main objective is to report adresses and then display all adresses in a google map, for which I have my custom controller and where I need to access the service layer

Comment: I am not very clear on your question, my guess.. You want to call `ReportService.findAllReports()` from you `CustomController`, is that you want?

Comment: yes i just want to call this function but i'm not aware of how to get the instance of ReportService or how to inject it to my own controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly `@Autowired` it as follows.

```
@Controller
public class CustomController {
    @Autowired
    ReportService reportService; //this inject's your bean here.

    List<Report> getReports() {
        return reportService.findAllReports();
    }
}
```

If you don't use annotation `@Controller` and defined your bean in `xml`, then you can inject `ReportService` as a property (just remove `@Autowired` annotation) and write a setter for it.